# How to copy test data into live of stripe

Tags: node.js, mongodb, stripe-payments

I'm currently testing out integration between our service and the Stripe API and creating various test product using test Secret key. Now I am moving to production with live secret key.

I want copy test data into live either through dashboard or script.

Please help me out!

Comment: What type of data ? What have you tried ? Also please read :  [ask]

Comment: I added some subscriptions. I want to copy that subscriptions from test to live

Comment: That's not really something Stripe supports, you can't copy most things from test to live mode. You can copy your Products (https://stripe.com/docs/billing/prices-guide#create-product), but not anything else like actual active subscriptions.